# Python Multivariate Apply/Map/Applymap

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-apply

Trying to use apply/map for multiple column values. works fine for one column. Made an example below of applying to a single column, need help making the commented out part work for multiple columns as inputs.

I need it to take 2 values on same row but from different columns as inputs to the function, perform a calc, and then place the result in the new column. If there is an efficent/optimized way to do this with apply/map/or both please let me know, Thanks!!!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#gen some data to work with
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [2, 4, 6, 8],
                   'Col_2': [11, 22, 33, 44],
                   'Col_3': [2, 1, 2, 1]})

#Make new empty col to write to
df[4]=""

#some Function of one variable
def func(a):
    return(a**2)

#applies function itemwise to coll & puts result in new column correctly
df[4] = df['Col_1'].map(func)


"""
#Want Multi Variate version. apply itemwise function (where each item is from different columns), compute, then add to new column  

def func(a,b):
    return(a**2+b**2)

#Take Col_1 value and Col_2 value; run function of multi variables, display result in new column...???
df[4] = df['Col_1']df['Col_2'].map(func(a,b))


"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass each row of a dataframe as a Series, using apply function. And then in the function itself you can use its value according to the requirement.

`def func(df):
    return (df['Col_1']**2+df['Col_2']**2)`

`df[4] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)`

Do refer [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to explore.

Comment: If applying a very complex multivariate function (not just squares), can this way of doing it not generate incorrect results if it has to evalute entire column for each part of the execution compared to doing it itemwise for each "cell" ? If there is a need to do it item-wise how would I do that ?

Comment: I suppose I am after a itemwise solution; no example how to implement applymap for multivariables where each variable is a value from a different column in the same row. Please advise, Thanks.

Comment: "df" that we passed inside the apply function is itself the variable through which value from a different column in the same row can be access. I think this way it will work. If still not clear, can you elaborate on problem/error you are facing?